# Javascript Algorithm to combine slices of images to form single image

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas

I have slices of images, like 0_0.jpg, 0_1.jpg, 1_0.jpg. 1_1.jpg

I want to combine them to form one single image.

I have a canvas element already.

what library, or algorithm can do this?

UPDATE :
Complete senario :

I have to load few images into a CANVAS element. SOme of them are full images, not sliced. But few are sliced into pieces. what I want is to get combine those slices image into one. **Some people saying use table or css or whatever. that just won't work here.** I need some technique to convert them on fly.

Comment: Why do you think you'd need to combine them *before drawing*?

Comment: I think, if I won't be combining them before drawing, then I would need them to perfectly fix in the canvas.

The problem here is, user can ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT the canvas element(that combined Image). Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Nah, you can draw them everywhere in the canvas, even so that only parts of them are visible. How do you think your zoom works?

Comment: the images can ZOOM in and zoom out. And images are basically inside canvas element.

the images are single at first, when user zoom in then i have to load multiple slices of high resolution image, and show them on canvas. its okay if after zoom out the resolution is BIG.

Comment: And what does not work with this code?

Comment: Bergi, I need to merge images on fly. That means after combining ["catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_0.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_1.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_2.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_0.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_1.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_2.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/2_0.jpg", .. etc

I should get the url of image, since that is not possible with javascript i guess?? How can i get string of data/image to write as image source?

Comment: Please show us the code of your zoom-viewer (in your question), and we'll show you how to integrate sliced images.

Comment: Bergi, the code is pretty long and it will take time to understand it. 
Is it possible to generate a base64 data/image as source?
Or if is it possible generate a image with file name? something.jpg after merging all?

Comment: No, although you could use a second canvas to combine them before drawing the canvas element into the canvas, I'm quite sure this is not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this with canvas, you'll have to know all the dimensions and draw the Image objects.  Use the JS image object to preload your images.  From there you have all the information you need to 'stitch' them together, width, height, etc...

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

```
// Three arguments: the element, destination (x,y) coordinates.
context.drawImage(img_elem, dx, dy);

// Five arguments: the element, destination (x,y) coordinates, and destination 
// width and height (if you want to resize the source image).
context.drawImage(img_elem, dx, dy, dw, dh);

// Nine arguments: the element, source (x,y) coordinates, source width and 
// height (for cropping), destination (x,y) coordinates, and destination width 
// and height (resize).
context.drawImage(img_elem, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

Here's a example that's close to what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }

      window.onload = function(images) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var sources = {
          darthVader: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg",
          yoda: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg"
        };

        loadImages(sources, function(images) {
          context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
          context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
        });
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Personally, I'd simply use a table with zero padding and zero margin.  Much easier IMO.

Comment: I can't use table here. As I have to show this image in an canvas. And have to make a full image out of slices before displaying. Is it possible?

Comment: @SwatiSharma - The syntax to do it is already present in this answer. What else do you need?

Comment: will this convert images on fly? Also, I am not sure how to i control Coordinates. Can it be done without coordinates? 

becase there are multiple images, for some I have 4 slices, for some I have 6 slices.. etc

what is the best way?

Comment: Vilx, can it be saved to a javascript variable as well?

Like var test = context.drawImage(img_ele,x,y);

Comment: @SwatiSharma - I've added a link to my answer that tells you how to preload images using the JS Image object.  The object should provide you with all info you need to get started.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the url, it helping but I need to merge images on fly. That means after combining ["catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_0.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_1.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/0_2.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_0.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_1.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/1_2.jpg", "catalog_S_deepzoom/2202_files/10/2_0.jpg", .. etc

I should get the url of image, since that is not possible with javascript i guess?? How can i get string of data/image to write as image source? possible?

Comment: @SwatiSharma - so you want to do this server-side now?  Canvas is for the client.

Comment: Not server side. There is no point getting slices of images from server and then join them and again get a big image from server.

I want to pass that image to an element that creates images on canvas. So i want either a way to create an image , xyz.jpg on fly.. or data/image ? HELP :(

Comment: Chris, all your link says about is PRE LOADING images. 

though i asked about merging slices of images. my purpose is not yet solved. The above code will draw image on a canvas.. but then how to get the details of that draw.. like width, height, axis..

purpose not solved from any of your answer here.

Comment: @SwatiSharma - I don't have time to code the entire thing for you.  Please take the information, try something and if you get stuck, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `<canvas>`, but I'd just create a bunch of `<img>`s and position them absolutely so that they fit together. That will be simple, and work across all browsers, unlike `<canvas>`.

Comment: I have an canvas element already. I had to show multiple images on that canvas, some images don't need to be combined as they are one. 

But some are slices, and hence want to combine them to form one. And I have to do it on fly.. may be if i can get some login to combine, i can then convert it to data/image string ?